# NumberFormatException On ResourceController cannot cast from String to Integer

Tags: java, spring, rest, number-formatting

I have this controller with a get method that recive 3 paramaters as `java.lang.Integer`

```
@GetMapping(path = Constantes.CONSULTAR_NODO_SUCESOR)
    public ConsultarNodoSucesorResponse consultarNodoSucesor(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headerRequest,
                                                             @RequestParam(required = false) Integer idArbol, 
                                                             @RequestParam(required = false) Integer nivelFormulario, 
                                                             @RequestParam(required = false) Integer idSucesor,
                                                             @RequestParam(required = false) String rutaRelacion, 
                                                             @RequestParam(required = false) String tipoRelacion, 
                                                             HttpServletResponse headerResponse) {
        ConsultarNodoSucesorRequest request = new ConsultarNodoSucesorRequest(idArbol, nivelFormulario, idSucesor,
                rutaRelacion, tipoRelacion);
        return service.consultarNodoSucesor(headerRequest, request, headerResponse);
    }
```

When cosuming the server is returning code 400 for bad request, full error below

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"4111111111\
```

I'm sending in the paramter `idArbol` the value 4111111111 but It wont work, in the other hand when I send in that same paramters values like 1044444444 It works fine.

Why is this a thing? what is the max value of a `Integer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the value `1044444444` the value `4111111111` is too large for the `int` (and therefore `Integer`) data type, therefore is understood as `String`. The value overflows the allowed range for the integer.

See [Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> **int**: By default, the int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer, which has a minimum value of -231 and a maximum value of 231-1.

You might wonder why Spring behaves like that. This is the [Type Conversion](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc) feature of several annotations of Spring where `String` is the default value:

> Some annotated controller method arguments that represent String-based request input (such as `@RequestParam`, `@RequestHeader`, `@PathVariable`, `@MatrixVariable`, and `@CookieValue`) can require type conversion if the argument is declared as something other than String.
>
> For such cases, type conversion is automatically applied based on the configured converters. By default, simple types (`int`, `long`, `Date`, and others) are supported. You can customize type conversion through a `WebDataBinder` (see [`DataBinder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-initbinder)) or by registering Formatters with the `FormattingConversionServic`e. See [Spring Field Formatting](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#format).